# how to pass json parameters btween 2 files using module

Tags: javascript, json

i am trying to call function in other js file using require.all these the parameters

1. >       Login = require("LoginRequest");

> ```
>   Create = require("CreateView");
>   var params = { username : username.value , password : password.value};
>   var type ="POST"; 
>   var URL = "<a href="https://localhost/post_auth.php">https://localhost/post_auth.php</a>";
>   var Result;  </li>
> ```
>
> and here the call funcion from LoginScreen.js

```
b2.addEventListener('click',function(e)
{
    alert(params.username);
    if (username.value != '' && password.value != '')
    {

        Result=Login.Request(params,type,URL);
    }
    else
    {
        // warning alert
        alert("Username/Password are required");
    }


    if (Result.logged == true)
    {
        alert("Welcome " + Result.name + ", Please answer the following question");
        Create();
    }
    else
    {
        alert(Result.message);
    }
});
```

when i try to pass the parameters to LoginRequest.

```
function Request(params,type,url){
        var Result;
        var loginReq = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();

        loginReq.open(type,url);

        loginReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        //send parameters
        loginReq.send(JSON.stringify(params));

        loginReq.onload = function()
        {
            var json = this.responseText;
            Result = JSON.parse(json);
            alert (Result.logged);
            alert (Result.name);
        };
    return Result;
  };

exports.Request = Request;
```

the calling return undifiend object , where is my wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are making an async call.

when you call `loginReq.send()` the call will be made and it will continue executing the rest of the code without waiting for the async call to be finished, that's why the function returns `undefined`.

To fix this you can make a sync call instead of an async call (this is a bad bad bad idea) or you could restructure your code, maybe LoginRequest could return the loginReq instance instead of the result